# Enable / Activate shortcodes within homemade wordpress spoiler plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

> shortcodes (ultimate) doen't works within homemade wordpress spoiler

*(P.S.: Above is the initial title of my question. I've reworded it to be more general)*

## My issue:

I've created an homemade spoiler, based on [this tutorial](http://www.designerandgeek.com/2012/09/30/wordpress-plugin-tutorial-make-your-own-spoiler-shortcode/). It works great. However, the shortcodes-ultimate's shortcodes don't work when they are in the spoiler : it simply displays their source-code as plain text.

My question is how to "enable" those shortcodes within my spoiler?

Example : [Spoiler unfolded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8srOu.png)

---

## My code:

- ### WP page

  ```
  [su_button url="http://www.my-url.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/fileName.txt" download = "FileName.txt" background="#FF6B53" size="2" icon="icon: download" rel="download = 'fileName'"]download[/su_button]

  [dag_spoiler title="My spoiler"]
      [su_button url="http://www.my-url.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/fileName.txt" download = "FileName.txt" background="#FF6B53" size="2" icon="icon: download" rel="download = 'fileName'"]download[/su_button]
  [/dag_spoiler]
  ```

  (the two buttons are strictly identical)
- ### Homemade spoiler shortcode

#### PHP code

```php
<?php
/**
 * @package dag_spoiler
 * @version 0.1
 */
/*
Plugin Name: ebo Spoiler
Plugin URI: http://designerandgeek.com/dag-spoiler
Description: Spoilers!
Author: ebo ft. Designer and Geek
Version: 0.1
Author URI: http://designerandgeek.com/
*/


/**
* Adds a spoiler shortcode to WordPress.
* 
* @return   none    outputs HTML
*/

function dag_spoiler_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $default_title = __('Spoiler alert!');
    $helptext_show = __('fa-plus');
    $helptext_hide = __('fa-minus');
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'title' => 'Click to show spoiler',
    ), $atts ) );
    $spoiler = 
    '<div class="dag_spoiler">' .
    '<p class="dag_spoiler_header" ' . 
    'data-dag-spoiler-show="' . $helptext_show .'" '.
    'data-dag-spoiler-hide="' . $helptext_hide . '">' . $title . '</p>' .
    '<div class="dag_spoiler_content">' .

    $content . 
    '</div>' . 
    '</div>';

    return $spoiler;
}
add_shortcode( 'dag_spoiler', 'dag_spoiler_func' );

/*EOF*/

/**
 * Enqueue plugin css and javascript
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dag_enqueue' );
function dag_enqueue() {
    wp_register_style( 'dag-spoiler-style', plugins_url('/ebo-spoiler.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dag-spoiler-style' );
    wp_register_script( 'dag-spoiler-js', plugins_url('/ebo-spoiler.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dag-spoiler-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dag_enqueue' );
?>
```

#### JS source-code

```js
jQuery(document).ready( jQuery(function( $ ) {
    $(".dag_spoiler_header").each(function(){
    $(this).click( function() {
        var help_text_span = $(this).children('span.dag_spoiler_help_text');
        $(this).siblings('.dag_spoiler_content').slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        help_text_span.html(
            help_text_span.html() == '<i class="fa '+hide_text+'"></i>' ? '<i class="fa '+show_text+'"></i>' : '<i class="fa '+hide_text+'"></i>'
        );
        });
    });
    var show_text = $(this).attr('data-dag-spoiler-show');
    var hide_text = $(this).attr('data-dag-spoiler-hide');
    $(this).prepend(' <span class="dag_spoiler_help_text" style="margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 5px; font-size: 14px;"> <i class="fa '+show_text+'"></i></span>');
    });
}));
```

#### (just for exhaustiveness) CSS

```css
.dag_spoiler {
    margin: .5em 0 .5em 0;
}

.dag_spoiler .dag_spoiler_header {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dag_spoiler .dag_spoiler_header::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.dag_spoiler div.dag_spoiler_content {
    padding-left: 7%; 
    padding-right: 7%;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
do_shortcode($content)
```

In your spoiler shortcode. Like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package dag_spoiler
 * @version 0.1
 */
/*
Plugin Name: ebo Spoiler
Plugin URI: http://designerandgeek.com/dag-spoiler
Description: Spoilers!
Author: ebo ft. Designer and Geek
Version: 0.1
Author URI: http://designerandgeek.com/
*/


/**
* Adds a spoiler shortcode to WordPress.
* 
* @return   none    outputs HTML
*/

function dag_spoiler_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $default_title = __('Spoiler alert!');
    $helptext_show = __('fa-plus');
    $helptext_hide = __('fa-minus');
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'title' => 'Click to show spoiler',
    ), $atts ) );
    $spoiler = 
    /*'<style>'.
    '.dag_spoiler .dag_spoiler_header::before {'.
        'data-dag-spoiler-show="'. $helptext_show .'" '.
        'data-dag-spoiler-hide="'. $helptext_hide.'" '.
    '}'.
    '</style>'.*/
    '<div class="dag_spoiler">' .
    '<p class="dag_spoiler_header" ' . 
    'data-dag-spoiler-show="' . $helptext_show .'" '.
    'data-dag-spoiler-hide="' . $helptext_hide . '">' . $title . '</p>' .
    '<div class="dag_spoiler_content">' .
    /*'<p class="dag_spoiler_header">'. $title . '</p>' .
    '<div class="dag_spoiler_content">' .*/
    do_shortcode($content) . 
    '</div>' . 
    '</div>';

    return $spoiler;
}
add_shortcode( 'dag_spoiler', 'dag_spoiler_func' );

/*EOF*/

/**
 * Enqueue plugin css and javascript
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dag_enqueue' );
function dag_enqueue() {
    wp_register_style( 'dag-spoiler-style', plugins_url('/ebo-spoiler.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dag-spoiler-style' );
    /*wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );*/
    wp_register_script( 'dag-spoiler-js', plugins_url('/ebo-spoiler.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dag-spoiler-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dag_enqueue' );
?>
```

Comment: That's it! (for future dummies as I am : I replaced the line 36 of the `php` code by @dingo_d's solution.) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Feel free to up vote and accept my answer :) Happy to help

Comment: well, that's kinda embarrassing : this solution works (i.e. the button appear within the spoiler)... but generate an wp-admin blank page!

Comment: When you click on the button or on the spoiler? Turn on your debug to see if there are any messages. Also I'd recommend using accordion for 'spoiler' shortcode, since wordpress supports jquery-ui which can handle accordions.

Comment: [secondary issue solved] It was when I activated this plugin, after this very particular change that I couldn't log on `www.my-site.com/wp-admin` because this page was blank. But, my bad, I solved the issue: I had made a copy-paste of the code, whereas each line of the latter was 4 spaces indented. It was the indentation of the whole`php` code that generated the bug. Sorry... and thank you!